# State of Multi-Seat in Ubuntu 22.04 (or later)

Tags: desktop-environments, multiseat

I'm planning to have one computer and many people to work with it at the same time in the same room. I know that it is possible in principle but would like to ask:

1. Is multi-seat something that is officially supported by Ubuntu?
2. What DE (desktop environment) works best for multi-seat and which Ubuntu flavor should I use?
3. Are there graphical user interfaces to manage which displays, keyboards, mice and head sets are associated with the different seats?

Anyone who has successfully used Ubuntu 22.04 or later with a multi-seat setup is welcomed to answer this question.